# How do I append multiple data frames to empty DataFrame with Title

Tags: python, pandas

So I have multiple data frames df1, df2,and df3 with 8 columns with n rows.
I want to append them into an empty data frame with a title/header on top. and after each append I want
to create an empty space.

For example the final output would be:

```
                        Header/title                                
 c1     c2       c3      c4      c5       c6      c7     c8
data    data    data    data    data    data    data    data    
data    data    data    data    data    data    data    data    
                                
 c1     c2       c3      c4      c5       c6      c7     c8
data    data    data    data    data    data    data    data    
data    data    data    data    data    data    data    data    
                                
 c1     c2       c3      c4      c5       c6      c7     c8
data    data    data    data    data    data    data    data    
data    data    data    data    data    data    data    data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from random import randint

#This is just to generate dataframes I'm assuming you do not need this part.
n=7
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"column{}".format(i):[randint(1,100) for x in range(n)] for i, v in enumerate(range(8),1)})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"column{}".format(i):[randint(1,100) for x in range(n)] for i, v in enumerate(range(8),1)})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({"column{}".format(i):[randint(1,100) for x in range(n)] for i, v in enumerate(range(8),1)})

#this makes the empty space and the header rows (normally this works if you have the same amount of columns)
empty_space =  {d1:"" for d2, d1 in enumerate(df1.columns,0)}
col_col = {d1:d2 for d1, d2 in zip(df1.columns,df2.columns)}

#This appends data from df1 + df2 together (with your buffer space and headers, which are just values at this point)
output_df = df1.append(empty_space, ignore_index=True)
output_df = output_df.append(col_col, ignore_index=True)
output_df = output_df.append(df2, ignore_index=True)

#repeat for the 3 dataframe
col_col = {d1:d2 for d1, d2 in zip(output_df.columns,df3.columns)}
output_df = output_df.append(empty_space, ignore_index=True)
output_df = output_df.append(col_col, ignore_index=True)
output_df = output_df.append(df3, ignore_index=True)
```

This is strictly a consultative output as the dfs are not maintained as separated df in the output_df. For the title I don't know. I guess I'd try something involving multiindexing. But depending on the output it might be easier to just go directly in your Excel, HTML, JSON (or other) file and put it there directly.

I hope this'll help.